# How to set array as state in Reagent using ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to create a state called `items` however my code gives an error and I'm unsure of why when I try to access the items and iterate over them. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(def items (r/atom ["test" "test2"]))

(defn home-page []  
  [:div#main
    [:section.section
      [:h1#s-one-greeting "Hello, I'm testing"]
      [:h2#s-one-greeting-two "blah blah blah"]]
    [:section.section
      [:p "Work history"]
      [:p "yada"]
      [:p "yada"]
      [:ul
        (for [item items]
          ^{:key item} [:li "item " item])]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `items` without derefing it. So you are trying to `for` loop over the reagent `atom` which doesn't work. Just switch it to `(for [item @items] ...)` and you should be fine.

Comment: Why do we need to deref it?

Comment: Because an atom is a container. It's not the value it contains. `@items` is literally expanded to `(deref items)`, which gets the value held inside the atom. See: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref. Note that atoms aren't the only things that can be derefed. For example Reagent has `cursor` and `track`, which don't actually hold a value, but are instead calculated when `deref`ed